# Prove that $\gcd(2^n-1,n)=1$ with :

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, congruences

$n=pq$ with $p,\ q$ two different odd prime numbers such that $p<q<2p$.

Notice that $2^n-1\equiv 0 \pmod{2^n-1} \Leftrightarrow 2^n\equiv 1 \pmod{2^n-1}$.

So the order of $2$ (invertible) in $(\mathbb{Z}/(2^n-1)\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ divides $n=pq$. It also divides $\phi(2^n-1)$. We can deduce that this order divides $\gcd(\phi(2^n-1),n)$ but it will be difficult to conclude.

But we can also notice that the integer $2^n-1$ is necessarily odd so we can write $2^n-1=l_1^{\xi_1}...l_k^{\xi_k}$ with $l_i$ odd prime numbers.If we do not find $p$ and $q$ in that list it will be right.

$2^{n}-1=(2^{pq}-1)=(2^p-1)K=(2^q-1)K'$ with $K,K'\in \mathbb{Z}$. (What will be the expression $K'$ and $K$ in that case ??)

However by FlittleT we have for $2\in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ : $2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ (same for $q$) so $2^p \equiv 2 \pmod p$ (true for $2 \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$). So $p$ does not divide $2^p-1$ (same $q$ does not divide $2^q-1$). But how to conclude ?

I try to develop $K$ and $K'$ and prove that $p$ or $q$ does not divide dem but it's difficult to factorize these expressions because of prime numbers.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all we need is Fermat's little theorem. We know that (as you said) $$2^{pq} \equiv 2^q \pmod p$$ 
So $$2^{pq}-1 \equiv 2^q -1\pmod p$$ 
And so we want to know if $p|(2^q-1)$.

But if $$2^{q}-1 \equiv 0\pmod p$$ then by FLT again, $(p-1)$ and $q$ have a common factor. But $q>p$ and $q$ is prime so we can't have such a common factor.

Now if we switch the primes, we get that $(q-1)$ and $p$ have a common factor.So then as $p$ is prime we must have $p|(q-1)$.
But again this is impossible as $(q-1)<2p$.
So we get that neither $p$ nor $q$ can divide $2^n -1$ so we're done.

Comment: Thank you but at the end  we can say that the generator $2$ has order $p-1$ so $(p-1)$ divides $q$. It's absurd because $q$ is an odd prime and $p-1$ an even integer. Moreover $2$ has order $(q-1)$ so $(q-1)$ divides $p$, absurd.

How to factorize $2^{pq}-1$ to conclude my proof ?

Comment: Not quite no. We can only conclude that the order divides both $p-1$ and $q$ - This is then common factor that I mention. In both cases the argument still leads to a contradiction as I show!

Comment: You have that $2$ is a generator in that case so its order is $(p-1)$ or $(q-1)$

Comment: To conclude, we see that $2^{pq} -1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$ and $2^{pq} -1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod q$, So neither $p$ nor $q$ can divide $2^{pq}-1$, and since these could be the only possible common factors as the only faactors of $n$ we're done.

Comment: We cannot explicit $K$ and $K'$ with a factorization formula ?

Comment: Note 1) I'm still not convinced about $2$ being a generator; if we could we could use your proposed absurdity for the counter-example below. You haven't used the hypothesis you missed out yet. Note 2) As for a factorisation formula; $(2^{pq}-1)=(2^q-1)(2^{q(p-1)}+2^{q(p-2)}+...+1) = (2^p-1)(2^{p(q-1)}+2^{p(q-2)}+...+1)$.  You can try to prove directly that $p$ can't divide $K$ and $q$ can't divide $K'$ directly but I wouldn't recommend it. This is much slicker and shows $gcd(2^n-1,n)=1$ as you require.

Answer (score 0):

Take $n=3.7=21$ Then $2^n-1=2^{21}-1$ their $\gcd\neq1$.

Comment: Indeed I forget an hypothesis... Sorry